# Dividing a `tcolorbox` into more than 2 "side by side" parts

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

I know that it is possible to divide a `tcblowerbox` into 2 parts using the `\tcblower` command inside `\tcbitemize` and using the `sidebyside` option. But, is there any way to divide a `tcolorbox` into more than 2 side by side parts?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with a `tcbraster` where you can define as many divisions (`raster columns`) you need. Each `tcolorbox` inside the raster is independent but you can force them to have equal height. Boxes on same row are not breakable, but the raster is broken between row if it doesn't fit in one page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, sharp corners, 
                  raster equal height, raster column skip=-.5mm]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!30]
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]